# Strange behaviour of CUDA kernel

Tags: cuda

I'm writing code for calculating prefix sum. Here is my kernel

```
__global__ void prescan(int *indata,int *outdata,int n,long int *sums)  
{  
    extern __shared__ int temp[];  

    int tid=threadIdx.x;
    int offset=1,start_id,end_id;
    int *global_sum=&temp[n+2];

    if(tid==0)
    {
        temp[n]=blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
        temp[n+1]=blockDim.x*(blockIdx.x+1)-1;
        start_id=temp[n];
        end_id=temp[n+1];
        //cuPrintf("Value of start %d and end %d\n",start_id,end_id);

    }
    __syncthreads();
    start_id=temp[n];
    end_id=temp[n+1];
    temp[tid]=indata[start_id+tid];
    temp[tid+1]=indata[start_id+tid+1];


    for(int d=n>>1;d>0;d>>=1)
    {
        __syncthreads();
        if(tid<d)
        {
            int ai=offset*(2*tid+1)-1;
            int bi=offset*(2*tid+2)-1;

            temp[bi]+=temp[ai];
        }
        offset*=2;
    }

    if(tid==0)
    {  
        sums[blockIdx.x]=temp[n-1];  
        temp[n-1]=0;
        cuPrintf("sums %d\n",sums[blockIdx.x]);
    }
    for(int d=1;d<n;d*=2)
    {
        offset>>=1;
        __syncthreads();
        if(tid<d)
        {
            int ai=offset*(2*tid+1)-1;
            int bi=offset*(2*tid+2)-1;
            int t=temp[ai];
            temp[ai]=temp[bi];
            temp[bi]+=t;
        }
    }

    __syncthreads();

    if(tid==0)
    {
        outdata[start_id]=0;
    }

    __threadfence_block();
    __syncthreads();
    outdata[start_id+tid]=temp[tid];
    outdata[start_id+tid+1]=temp[tid+1];
    __syncthreads();

    if(tid==0)  
    {  
        temp[0]=0;  
        outdata[start_id]=0;  

    }  

    __threadfence_block();
    __syncthreads();

    if(blockIdx.x==0 && threadIdx.x==0)
    {
        for(int i=1;i<gridDim.x;i++)
        {
            sums[i]=sums[i]+sums[i-1];
        }
    }

    __syncthreads();
    __threadfence();

    if(blockIdx.x==0 && threadIdx.x==0)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<gridDim.x;i++)
        {
            cuPrintf("****sums[%d]=%d ",i,sums[i]);
        }
    }


    __syncthreads();
    __threadfence();


    if(blockIdx.x!=gridDim.x-1)
    {
        int tid=(blockIdx.x+1)*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
        if(threadIdx.x==0)
            cuPrintf("Adding %d \n",sums[blockIdx.x]);
        outdata[tid]+=sums[blockIdx.x];

    }
    __syncthreads();

}
```

In above kernel, sums array will accumulate prefix sum per block and and then first thread will calculate prefix sum of this sum array. Now if I print this sum array from device side it'll show correct results while in

> cuPrintf("Adding %d \n",sums[blockIdx.x]);

this line it prints that it is taking old value. What could be the reason?

Comment: I'm using \__threadfence everywhere even though unnecessary , but still it is strange any clue?

Comment: as a quick fix, you could try to declare the array 'sums' volatile. It might be that the compiler caches the results in registers, i.e. when you compute: sums[i]=sums[i]+sums[i-1]; Though I am not entirely sure..

Comment: What do you mean "prints that it is taking old value".  What exactly is going wrong?  When posting really long code like this you can't expect people to understand it perfectly -- you need to be very explicit about what is happening and what your question is.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not a valid implementation of multi-block prefix sum.  You are trying to use a single thread of block 0 to compute the prefix sum of the partial block sums, before those partial block sums are guaranteed to have been written to memory.  `__syncthreads()` only synchronizes threads in a single block, not across blocks.  So in this code:

```
__threadfence_block();
__syncthreads();

if(blockIdx.x==0 && threadIdx.x==0)
{
    for(int i=1;i<gridDim.x;i++)
    {
        sums[i]=sums[i]+sums[i-1];
    }
}
```

All blocks are not guaranteed to have computed their sums[blockIdx.x] before block 0 executes this code.  In fact, if you launch more blocks than can run concurrently on the device, all blocks are not guaranteed to have even started when you reach this code.

To make this code correct, you need to end the kernel before this code, and launch a new kernel to compute the block prefix sum result, and another one to add the result of that to each thread block.